# Are impact protection goggles worth it for Muay Thai for someone who can't take hits to the eye?

Tags: muay-thai, injury, protective-equipment

Disclaimer: I don't consider anything here to be professional advice.

I want to start Muay Thai but I don't want to get hits to the eye due to an eye condition called keratoconus.

I was considering going for caged headgear, but I'm not sure I want to sacrifice that much peripheral vision if there are alternatives, and I've read the use of headgear may increase brain damage long term than not using it.

So now I'm leaning onto sports goggles like [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B07KX651JP?psc=1&ref=ppx_pop_mob_b_asin_title). I've used this one before when playing soccer, and I once took a full hit to the face from a very fast ball at close range. My eyes suffered no damage and I only sustained a minor cut on the bridge of my nose.

I've also been testing them by punching myself in eyes with 16oz gloves. I gradually increased the punching power and I didn't feel anything too adverse and the goggles remained intact. Of course I understand I'm limited in how much I can fully test this out by myself.

I wanted to know if this could be worth it or not before I actually turn up to a club or if there are risks I should be considering here?

Comment: This is a question for your doctors, not for martial arts people. Yes, eye protection is something allowed in just about any martial arts school anywhere. I've never seen an instructor refuse to allow students to wear it. As for you, are you sure getting hit directly in the eye is the only thing you're trying to prevent? What about strikes to the head, too? The impact of a head strike might be just as bad as a direct hit to the eyes in your case. Nobody here would know that. Only your doctor would. Even still, you can minimize risk by telling sparring partners to go light. FYI.

Comment: Seconding @SteveWeigand on the need for you to talk to a doctor - it is also worth talking to the potential Muay Thai school(s) - They will have their own requirements for insurance purposes and may have restrictions on what you can wear.

Comment: Something to think about (not making any recommendations): Any time you wear any gear, you are redirecting, concentrating, and/or dispersing impact forces.  This is often a good thing.  But with inappropriate gear, this can be a bad thing.  (I have boxed for many years with and without headgear, but have never considered trying sports goggles in this context, so I really can't say more except that sports goggles have saved my eyes during lower impact activities.)